# So i have to write down a function that return shape

Tags: python

I need to write a function print_rect(ch, width, height) that prints out the character ch in the shape of a rectangle. The rectangle should have the dimensions width * height. For example:

> > > print_rect('*', 7, 5)

```
   *******
   *******
   *******
   *******
   *******
```

but the problem is that I can't make it any parameter I want it. for example if I write down print('?', 7, 5) it should give me rectangle shape with ? marks but it always gives me  ch rectangle.
what i have written as my formula is:

```
 def print_rect(ch, width, height):
    for ch in range(height):
    print ( "ch" * width)
    and my output is

    chchchchch
    chchchchch
    chchchchch
    chchchchch
    chchchchch
    chchchchch
    chchchchch
```

Hopefully i was clear in requirement, sorry if i made mistakes in explaining, english is not my first language.

Comment: not `print ( "ch" * width)`  ... but `print ( ch  * width)` - voting to close as typo.

Comment: Also, `for ch in range(height):` You want to use a different name for that variable as you are overwriting the `ch` parameter.

Comment: how do you guys write formula in stackoverflow and it appears in gray, it looks so professional and neat

Comment: @No_name https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. For specifically comments go to the [comment formatting section](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp what if I want to write the function for another shape such as  `***** **** *** ** *` I have written  `def print_upper_left_triangle(ch, height):
    width = height
    for i in range(height,0,-1):
            print(ch) ` but it gives me `5 of *` in height instead of `*****
 ****
 ***
 **
 *`

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over width and height, and print out the character in each iteration:

```
def print_rect(ch, width, height):
    for h in range(height):
        for w in range(width):
            print(ch,end='')
        print()
```

Demo:

```
print_rect('ch',5,6)
chchchchch
chchchchch
chchchchch
chchchchch
chchchchch
chchchchch

print_rect('*',3,2)
***
***
```

---

You could also do it your way (which is more elegant):

```
def print_rect(ch, width, height):
    for h in range(height):
        print(ch*width)
```

But you have to make sure `ch` is a string. But you could convert `ch` to a string:

```
def print_rect(ch, width, height):
    for h in range(height):
        print(str(ch)*width)
```

Comment: your formula worked. Can you please explain me why you write print(ch, end = ' ' ) and print(). Thanks in advance

Comment: `print(ch, end = ' ' )` prints `ch` without a newline, and `print()` prints just a newline. Personally, I prefer OP's original method of `print (ch * width)` .

Comment: Yep, the default argument for `end` is `'\n'`, meaning when you call print, it will put a newline at the end of your print statement.

Comment: @JoePatten what if I want to write the function for another shape such as  `***** **** *** ** *` I have written  `def print_upper_left_triangle(ch, height):
    width = height
    for i in range(height,0,-1):
            print(ch) ` but it gives me `5 of *` in height instead of `*****
 ****
 ***
 **
 *`

Comment: Your code looks fine, except your print statement would be `print(ch*i)`. `print_upper_left_triangle('*',5)` gives me: `*****
****
***
**
*`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 main things going on here. 
1. in the print line you call for the string "ch" to be printed instead of the argument ch.
2. in your for loop you use ch, but you are already using that as your character. I used x instead.

```
def print_rect(ch, width, height):
  for x in range(height):
    print (ch* width)
```

Comment: @JulieKirpatrick   what if I want to write the function for another shape such as  `***** **** *** ** *` I have written  `def print_upper_left_triangle(ch, height):
    width = height
    for i in range(height,0,-1):
            print(ch) ` but it gives me `5 of *` in height instead of `*****
 ****
 ***
 **
 *`

Comment: In your print statement, you only print ch once. you want to print it i times.
So replace `print(ch)` with `print(ch * i)`